# Dynamically limiting the space dedicated to certain folders

Tags: bash, filesystems, mount, partition

I am currently building a server application  on ubuntu 16.04, where users can register and upload their files in. To prevent people from uploading TB of data, i wanted to limit the size of the user directory, to an arbitrary size. 
NOTE that the user folder is *NOT* the folder of the unix user, but a folder that i created for the user i have in my web application.
To do so, i now call these commands from the server application:

```
touch /storage/partitionFile
truncate -s 1G /storage/partitionFile
mke2fs -t ext4 -F /storage/partitionFile
mount /storage/partitionFile /home/sizeRestrictedFolder
```

This way i have a partition file saved somewhere in my storage and that file is mounted on the user folder.
This is the output of `df -h` ( I show only the new partition to keep it short ) :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       11M  108K  9.7M   2% /home/sizeRestrictedFolder
```

All this works but now i want these mounts to be kept after rebooting, and eventually even to increase the size of the partition.

For the partition after rebooting problem, i do not know on what fileSystem it will be mounted on, because for example user1 will be mounted on `/dev/loop0` then user 2 on `/dev/loop1` and so on...so i would not know how to edit `/etc/fstab` dynamically.

For the resize partition problem, i have tried quota and fdisk, but both ended up not working.

Is my approach even correct?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Building a server with Ubuntu 16.04 is not a good idea in 2021. I would strongly recommend a contemporary system. For quota constraints, [Btrfs quotas](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Quota_support) appear to be an exact match for your use case — no need for loopbacks, no need for partitioning, no need for _any_ kind of static pre-allocation… Plus you get a state-of-the-art filesystem with data checksums, CoW, atomic snapshots (vital for consistent backups), *silent data corruption* detection + resilience, online scalability from single-drive setups to RAID etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, i will look into it. I will definetly upgrade to a more recent ubuntu server, this is just an old server pc i had running a while ago and wanted to do some testing before upgrading. I will look into your solution as soon as i can, and then you can write all that as an answer so i can accept it :)